# Change Date appearence before DisplayDateStart date in datepicker

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I have a WPF application, in which I have a `datepicker` :

```
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedDate="{Binding DateP, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  DisplayDateStart="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

I'd like to change the appearence of dates before the `DisplayDateStart` date. Now these dates are hidden

1. How can I do this?
2. What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the dates using the `DisplayDateStart` you can specify the `BlackoutDates` so that the dates will be displayed but not selectable. This way you can style your `DatePicker` and apply one you prefer for non selectable dates (it is crossed out in default style).

More on the topic: [MSDN: DatePicker.BlackoutDates Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but still I can't bind the `End` and `Start` Properties  in `CalendarDateRange` tag

Comment: @LamloumiAfif that is true, but as far as im a concerned you can go around this by an attached property, like [here](http://wpfplayground.com/2014/07/28/wpf-datepicker-blackoutdates-data-binding/)

Answer (score 0):

WPF doesn't seem to offer a VisualState for these hidden items.  However, you can use a trigger on the CalendarDayButton style's ControlTemplate.  In the below example I'm collapsing the hidden date items to avoid the unnecessary whitespace.

```
<Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton" x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle">
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5" />
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
        <Grid x:Name="dayButtonContainer">
          // ... your presentation display
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden">
            <Setter TargetName="dayButtonContainer" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Setter TargetName="dayButtonContainer" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]